# Device Scanning for music files using HTML5 File API

Tags: html, file, api, blackberry-webworks

I am working with Blackbery 10 Webworks and I would like to add a feature of scanning music files from device and get their information like artist name, album, etc.

Can this be achieved using HTML5 File API? If yes how can that be done, a small working example would be helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but in theory this seems sound. First, I'd check out this blog here:
http://ericbidelman.tumblr.com/post/8343485440/reading-mp3-id3-tags-in-javascript

The one issue is that it leverages FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer, whereas BB10 does not have this implemented yet (but it does have readAsDataURL and readAsText):
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/filereader.html

We can look at each function in detail here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Finally, here is how to convert from a string (readAsText) to an ArrayBuffer (readAsArrayBuffer):
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

So, technically if we read the file as a string and do our conversion to ArrayBuffer, we should be able to implement the approach in the first URL above to pull ID3 information from a file.

Please note that I haven't tested this myself yet.